# ¿Como generar un ejecutable de python que lee de un excel con cx_freeze u otra herramienta?

Tags: python, excel, exe, cx-freeze

He hecho un programita de python que genera un formulario para que un usuario rellene por consola, las preguntas y respuestas que salen por pantalla están en un archivo excel. 
¿Cómo puedo generar un ejecutable del py y del excel para que alguien no tenga que tener python instalado en su ordenador?

He estado intentando crear el .exe con cx_freeze pero al generar el .exe y hacer click en él se cierra la consola. El código que usé fue este para generar la build del ejecutable:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
    setup( name = "ventana",
    version = "0.1" ,
    description = "ventana" ,
    executables = [Executable("LectorBDD.py")] , )
```

¿Necesito agregar algo más a este código?

No necesariamente tengo que usar cx_freeze, si alguien sabe como generar el ejecutable de otra forma y me lo podría explicar también es bienvenido. 
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Amaya, bienvenida a [es.so] ¿Tu problema es cómo incluir el xlsx en el ejecutable o tienes algún otro problema además de éste?

Comment: Hola FLSevilla, si mi problema es que no se como generar un ejecutable en python que lea de un Excel.

Comment: Pero el programa en si ya lo tienes y trabaja correctamente con el xlsx ¿no? El problema te surge al crear el exe, posiblemente porque no lo incluye y no encuentra el archivo posteriormente. Por cierto, ¿escribes en el archivo en algún momento o te limitas a leer solo?

Comment: Hola, si el programa  me funciona bien porque tengo instalado Python en mi ordenador pero quiero enviarselo a otro ordenador que no tiene Python para que se pueda ejecutar. El programilla del archivo .py lee de un excel para mostrar prreguntas en base a las respuestas del usuario, así que el programa le dice: "pregunta 1: respuesta 1 o respuesta 2" y el usuario escribe por le cmd "respuesta 1" y en base a esa respuesta 1 el programa le pregunta otra pregunta diferente a la que hubiera preguntado si el usuario hubiera respondido la 2.

Answer (score 0):

En principio, el problema obvio es que el archivo .xlsx no se va a incluir en el ejecutables. Para que el archivo xlsx sea incluido se debe agregarse su ruta dentro de las opción [`build_exe`](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#build-exe) con `include_files` del `setup.py`.

Dicha clave (dado que es un diccionario) debe ser una lista que contiene archivos para copiar en el directorio de destino. Debe contener cadenas o tuplas de dos elementos (`(ruta_origen, ruta_destino)`). Las rutas deben ser siempre relativas, no absolutas.

Si tenemos nuestro programa estructurado como:

> ```
> MainDir
> |
> |--LectorBDD.py
> |
> |--archivo.xlsx
> |
> |--setup.py
> ```

basta con:

```
# setup.py
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = "ventana",
    version = "0.1" ,
    description = "ventana",
    options = {'build_exe': {'include_files': ["archivo.xlsx"]}},
    executables = [Executable("LectorBDD.py")]
    )
```

Si tenemos nuestros archivos en un subdirectorio basta con pasar la ruta relativa al `setup.py` de ese o esos directorios:

> ```
> MainDir
> |
> |--LectorBDD.py
> |
> |--recursos
> |  |--archivo.xlsx
> |
> |--setup.py
> ```

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = "ventana",
    version = "0.1" ,
    description = "ventana",
    options = {'build_exe': {'include_files': ["./recursos"]}},
    executables = [Executable("LectorBDD.py")]
    )
```

Si por alguna razón nuestro programa necesita trabajar con rutas absolutas (por ejemplo crea directorios en la máquina en la que es ejecutado independientemente del directorio de trabajo dónde se ejecuta), lo anterior no basta porque en cada sistema la ruta variará. En ese caso hay que agregar una pequeña función que nos retorne la ruta adecuada en cada caso, tenemos un ejemplo en la propia documentación oficial:

- [Frequently Asked Questions- Using data files](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files)

---

> **Nota:** Cuando el ejecutable falle cerrándose la terminal inmediatamente, para saber que está pasando , en vez de ejecutarlo mediante doble click, abrir una terminal, colocarse en ese directorio y ejecutarlo desde la misma. De esta forma la terminal no se cerrara tras terminal el programa y podremos ver las excepciones.